# How to turn js variable to js object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

I'm parsing to html template this data:

```
[ 
   {
        "name": "1", 
        "children": [
            {"name": "2"}, 
            {"name": "3"}, 
            {"name": "4"}, 
            {"name": "5"}, 
            {"name": "6"}, 
            {"name": "7"}
        ]
    } 
]
```

in order to create a graph but to create it, this data should return type object (alert returns [object Object]).
When I copy-paste this exact same data to var in js to create a graph it works perfectly but while assigning it as:

```
    var data = '{{ node_data }}';
    var remove = data.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
    var final_data = remove.replace(/&#x27;/g, ' ');
```

It isn't working at all. I have also tried to use JSON.parse() but it doesn't return anything.
How can I change the type of var final_data to object?

Comment: `[...]` -> array, `{...}` -> object

Answer (score 1):

Since JSON's syntax is borrowed from JavaScript's, when outputting a `<script>`, it's often possible to insert JSON as-is where JavaScript expects an *Expression*. In this case, with the variable assignment, that should mean the quotations around `{{ node_data }}` aren't necessary.

Granted, as the following `replace` suggests, the view engine can output `node_data` encoded with HTML entities (`&quot;`, etc.), that can conflict with removing the quotes. You haven't noted which view engine you're using, though many that use braces ("mustaches") allow for using triple braces to disable HTML encoding.

So, adjusting for both of those, try this:

```js
var final_data = {{{ node_data }}};
```

The result sent to the client/browser should be similar to:

```js
var final_data = [{"name": "1","children":[...]}]; // `...` just for brevity
```

(If the triple braces aren't supported by your current view engine, could you note which engine you are using?)